# styling two level menu (second level)

Tags: html, css, menu

I have two level horizontal menu that works fine.
Second level is not a drop down, it appears on first level menu item click and stays horizontally just under the first level menu.

I need first and second level menu **always start from the left side of the container** and be **full width** of the container Currently only first level works like this, but second level doesn't. It starts just under active first level menu item.

You can see it in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GrBXa/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-top-menu" class="main_nav">
                <li><a>H1</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Prevent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Avoid</a></li>
                        <li><a>P2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Sol</a>    
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a>Jan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Janu2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Janu3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Why </a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li><a href="">Electri</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Envir</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Manag</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.main-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    height: 38px;
    border-top: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
}
.main-navigation ul {
}
.main-navigation li, .main-navigation li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
#menu-top-menu {
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu-top-menu>li>a {
    border-bottom: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-top-menu>li>a, #menu-top-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu-top-menu>li >a {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
#menu-top-menu>li:hover, .main-navigation ul>li>a:hover {
    background-color: #061361;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #061361;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
.sub-menu li {
    display: inline;
}
.sub-menu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    color: white;
}
#menu-top-menu>li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 14px;
}
#menu-top-menu li.current-menu-item ul, #menu-top-menu li.current-menu-parent ul {
    display: inline;
}
#menu-top-menu li.current-menu-item a, #menu-top-menu li.current-menu-parent a {
    background-color: #061361;
    color: white;
}
```

I believe that this could be done using some relative positioning, but I was not able to achieve this. I have problems with positioning. Please, give me some guidelines.

Comment: Your jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GrBXa/1/) is quite bad for a contextual example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `left:0; width:100%;` to your .sub-menu rules.

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #061361;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GrBXa/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'm a little unclear as to what you were looking for - however, I'll try to help out how I can.

I added the following styles to your existing CSS definitions:

```
#menu-top-menu {
    position:relative;
}

.sub-menu {
    left:0;
    bottom:-26px;
    margin-left:40px;
    width:100%;
}
```

You'll note that I did use `position:relative`, as you suspected would be the case. Here's an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrBXa/9/) demonstrating what these additional styles achieve.

If this isn't what you were looking for, feel free to let me know and I'll be happy to help you further. Good luck!